# RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED in backward pass in Torch

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I am working on a Pytorch code of Autoencoder. The training set contains images of shape `batchsize*3*height*width`. The model's code is too big to put here. Some codes are:

```
model = Network()
model.cuda()
#loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss = nn.BCELoss()
optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
```

I got the output of the forward pass simply with the line:

```
y_pred = model( torch.tensor(train, dtype= torch.float).cuda())
```

This gives output of shape `batchsize*3*height1*width1`. I made the groundtruths of the same shape.

The loss is called by this line individually:

```
l = loss(y_pred, my_list_resized.cuda())
```

And it is working perfectly so far...

However, when I try it in loops for epochs:

```
for epoch in range(1):
    y_pred = model( torch.tensor(train, dtype= torch.float).cuda())
    l = loss(y_pred, my_list_resized.cuda())
    optim.zero_grad()
    l.backward()
    optim.step()
```

this gives the error in line l.backward():

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-99d4765682f1> in <module>
----> 1 l.backward()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    219                 retain_graph=retain_graph,
    220                 create_graph=create_graph)
--> 221         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    222 
    223     def register_hook(self, hook):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
    128         retain_graph = create_graph
    129 
--> 130     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    131         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph,
    132         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag

RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
```

individually running l.backward() that is outside the epcoh also gives this error. ANy solution please?

Comment: have you tried running this code on your cpu because sometimes that gives a more specific error to tell you what is wrong?

Comment: running in cpu exceeds memory. i dont know how but i could solve it by changing the loss to L1 loss

Comment: Ok sometimes this error is because the outputs of your model don't match your labels are you sure they are the same size? Also does your pytorch have the same cuda version as your gpu?

Comment: @DwightFoster, thanks for the questions. I absolutely made sure that these 2 questions are solved. that is I checked that the output and label are of same shape and the versions of cuda and gpu are same. as i said, I had something to do with the loss function. I don't know what though. I changed the loss function from crossentropy to L1 and it worked